# Javascript link system

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am programming dynamic CMS and I have little problem:
I want to write on page links like `<a href="/products/...">product</a>`, but these links can not be clickable. (I have javascript code to load link page content to `<div class="main"></div>` - page must be dynamical and it can't refresh).
This is code:

```
function loadPage(page) {
    $(".main").load("http://" + window.location.hostname + page + "/data.html");
    window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "http://" + window.location.hostname + page);
}
```

some link in menu:

```
<a class="menuItem" href="/home">
    Home
</a>
```

and jquery:

```
$("a").click(function (){
    loadPage($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Is it possible? Or have anyone better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but these links can not be clickable

You *do* want them to be "clickable" (and indeed you *explicitly* add a click handler), you just don't want them to perform their *default action* of page navigation.

You can prevent that with a combination of `preventDefault()` and `return false`.  Something like this:

```
$("a").click(function (e){ // note the event parameter here
    loadPage($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```